# jsf automatic scroll to top in viewscoped bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a viewscoped managed bean and using preRenderView event, I reload the page when user makes a selection and content needs to be changed on basis of this selection.

```
<f:event listener="#{mybean.initialize()}" type="preRenderView"/>
```

Now, when the page reloads, it scrolls to top and in order to see the updated content, you have to scroll down. I want the updated content to be displayed when the page reloads without scrolling down. 
I have tried using redirect with facescontext as follows:

```
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  context.getExternalContext().redirect(contacthistory.xhtml#showform");
```

But, this approach does not work because the bean is created again.I have found lots of approaches using javascript and jquery, but I am unable to use javascript according to the project requirements. So, how can I achieve this scroll down?

Comment: It's impossible without some form of js (somebody correct me if I'm wrong). The redirect is working as designed however. You've placed an anchor element on the webpage. You have to get to it *somehow* and a full page navigation is not an option. Your options are to either redirect in full (and lose the viewscoped bean) or use some rudimentary js to scroll to the anchor

Comment: JSF frameworks, no matter which one you use, it does embed JavaScript in your xhtml files, so it is impossible not use Javascript.